# Joining Pandas dataframes based on time intervals and calculating average values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, group-by

Have a tricky question:

There are two dataframes 'TimeRanges' where the information about ranges of time is in (start date and end date with ID) like this:

```
ID  StartTime       EndTime
1   01.03.18 12:00  01.03.18 13:00 
2   01.03.18 13:00  01.03.18 13:15 
3   01.03.18 13:30  01.03.18 14:55
```

The second dataframe contains Time column with the time values increasing with frequency of one minute and the column Values like this:

```
Time            Value
01.03.18 12:00  5.00
01.03.18 12:01  20.00
01.03.18 12:02  5.00
01.03.18 13:10  30.00
01.03.18 14:20  45.00
```

What I try to achieve and don't know how to come closer to the task is that I want to create new column AvgValue in dataframe TimeRanges which will contain mean() function of the Values those Times are in the interval between StartTime and EndTime for example:

```
ID  StartTime       EndTime         AvgValue
1   01.03.18 12:00  01.03.18 13:00     10
2   01.03.18 13:00  01.03.18 13:15     30
3   01.03.18 13:30  01.03.18 14:55     45
```

*The value 10 because it's in the interval from 01.03.18 12:00 to 01.03.18 13:00 (01.03.18 12:00, 01.03.18 12:01, 01.03.18 12:02) and because of that we calculate the mean only for these values.

What will be approach to do that? lambdas functions? or smth else?

Thanks

Comment: You used an hour interval in your example but you are not always grouping by hour, correct? Otherwise you could just group by hour and take the means

Comment: Yeah it can be different-20 min, 1 hour 40 min

Comment: I reupdated my question that it can be more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this with `resample` but it also requires a bit of fiddling so it might not be the best solution. First of all we need to the index to be of type DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex.

```
# set Time to be index
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
# change index type to datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

using `resample` - I have used the rule of 60 minutes. You can look at the rules in the follwoing link [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
new_df = df.resample('60T').mean().reset_index()
```

now we have a `new_df` with average values every 60 minutes. we just need to do the following to have it in the format you want.

```
from datetime import timedelta    
new_df['EndTime'] = new_df['Time'] + timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

and finally renaming the columns:

```
new_df.rename(columns={'Time': 'StartTime', 'Value': 'AvgValue'}, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    StartTime             AvgValue    EndTime
0   2018-01-03 12:00:00   10.0        2018-01-03 13:00:00
1   2018-01-03 13:00:00   30.0        2018-01-03 14:00:00
2   2018-01-03 14:00:00   45.0        2018-01-03 15:00:00
```

> > EDIT: This time using the first dataframe (df1) for the time ranges you can do the following

```
df1['AvgTime'] = df1.T.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x['StartTime']:x['EndTime']].mean()).T
```

Comment: it's really cool but what if the StartTime and EndTime are not always in 1 hour interval and can vary: for example 20 min, 34 min. Are these some workarounds for this situation?

Comment: right.. so you want to find out the frequency of your data and use that rather than you specifying it ? But you can change the `60T` in the `resample` function to whatever you like and just amend the `timedelta` to the correct interval

Comment: but I mean they are all different from row to row the intervals, how can it be unified?

Comment: ooh sorry i see what you mean now. let me give it another go:)

Comment: I've just update my answer which should be exactly what you're looking for. Just remember to still set the index of your second dataframe to datetime index.. this will allow us to get data between 2 dates like the follwoing `df.loc['date1':'date2']`

Comment: @HalfPintBoy does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/).

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df1, 
    ('Time', 'StartTime', '>='), 
    ('Time', 'EndTime', '<='))
.groupby(['ID', 'StartTime', 'EndTime'], as_index = False)
.Value
.mean()
)

   ID           StartTime             EndTime  Value
0   1 2018-01-03 12:00:00 2018-01-03 13:00:00   10.0
1   2 2018-01-03 13:00:00 2018-01-03 13:15:00   30.0
2   3 2018-01-03 13:30:00 2018-01-03 14:55:00   45.0
```